# Can't install Ubuntu 13.10 from 12.04 lts

Tags: installation, 13.10, hp, radeon, live-cd

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts installed on my hp pavilion and I want to try 13.10. When I try to boot into the livecd, I get the purple ubuntu splash screen, then a blackscreen where some text flashes (to fast to see what it says) then it goes to a black screen and stays there. I know the installation disc is not the problem because I've successfully installed it on a different machine using the same disc. I've been trying to troubleshoot the issue for a while now and no luck. I have a radeon hd 8250 card. I know it's not much to go off of but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo do-release-upgrade`? Will it let you update to a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try the Ubuntu 13.10 live CD, you can safely try it without installing Ubuntu 13.10, assuming that you can find a solution to the problem that the Ubuntu 13.10 live CD is booting to a black screen.

You can also [upgrade directly from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) without any additional complications. That is because both Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 are Long Term Support (five year support) releases, and it is possible to upgrade from a Long Term Support release to the next Long Term Support release. It is also highly recommended not to skip over the next supported release in the distribution upgrade path when doing a distribution upgrade. So you can upgrade directly to either Ubuntu 12.10 or Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need grub or terminal to do this....

`sudo apt-get update` then  this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` then `sudo apt-get update` again, now this `sudo apt-get install unity` once all this loads.... Type `startx`